# Pass function with parameters in context provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am starting on React and I am finding it difficult to implement the email and password in the context.

The example I'm following only shows no parameters.

Ty for any help

```
async function signIn(email: string, password: string) {
        const response = await auth.signIn(email, password);
    }
    
    
     return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{signed: !!user, 
            user: user, loading, 
            signIn: signIn(), 
            logout}}>
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the function, but instead the result of the function being called. You should change `signIn: signIn(),` to `signIn: signIn,` or just `signIn,`

Comment: I try, but show the following error: (method) AuthContextData.signIn(): Promise<void>
Type '(email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<void>'.ts(2322)
auth.context.tsx(15, 3): The expected type comes from property 'signIn' which is declared here on type 'AuthContextData'

Comment: @GiovanniDias Could you please provide the extended code for where you define the context types like `AuthContextData` and where you actually use the function from the context?

Comment: my mistake, i dont declare parameters on interface holy, thank you